# Can't control the display brightness on Lenovo X1 yoga OLED

Tags: display, brightness

I'm with 16.10 and Yoga X1 OLED beast of a laptop but unfortunately can't control the display brightness. It's at the maximum. Both the keyboard and settings control move the slide bar but it does nothing to the actual brightness and it stays at maximum.

Comment: You may be suffering from this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1667323

Comment: Not sure.
It changes the vlaue in:

/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

but that doesn't affect the actual screen brightness.

Seems to be OLED related problem

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: Have you tried `xbacklight` command? it will somehow change `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`, anyway gibe it a shot: `xbacklight -set 50`.

Comment: Can you try running this command in terminal and see if the brightness changes:
`echo 2000 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

Comment: (repost from other issue) Update, there's a Wayland solution now, http://github.com/udifuchs/icc-brightness; icc-brightness watch and then use your regular brightness keys. Yay!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just stumbled on this question, looking for an answer I gave a while ago regarding OLED screens in X11. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824949/lenovo-thinkpad-x1-yoga-oled-brightness/849642#849642). I normally bind some variations of the command to some keys, so I can switch fast:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness 1   # no dimming
xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness .5  # dim to half
```

Entering xrandr by itself shows the device-name to be used (`eDP1` or `eDP-1` or the like). The number can be anything between 0 and 1.

Floating point numbers can be used. If the value is greater than 1 screen goes above normal brightness but colors become saturated.

Comment: Finally something that work! It just was another name for me eDP-1

Answer (score 1):

Two options to manually change the display brightness:

`xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness $brightness`

`redshift -P -O $temperature -b $brightness`

$brightness is a value between 0 and 1 for xrandr and between 0.1 and 1 for redshift. It's the same value, but redshift prevents you from using values lower than 0.1 (which can lead to totally dark screen)

`$temperature` is the night light temperature. Use 6500 for daylight (no night light), 3500 is a common night filter value.

I've heard that the redshift method also works on Wayland.

You might be interested in [this project](https://github.com/lawleagle/oled-linux), which takes full advantage of these commands to bring back full-featured brightness control to your OLED display (sounds weird to say "full featured something that should work out of the box", but such is life. Check it out, most likely you'll love it)

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to this:

> recently we began to receive feedback in regards to the non-OLED models that either the display brightness keys (F5/F6) do not work to change the brightness

http://thinkdeploy.blogspot.is/2017/03/thinkpad-x1-yoga-20fq-20fr-darkblack.html

Comment: This seems to be the opposite problem and offering windows solution?

Answer (score 0):

The Alienware 13 r3 with OLED screen seems to have the same issue. The only solution is to use xrandr, but that does not work on Wayland​.