# Cannot set brightness on lenovo x1 yoga

Tags: lenovo, brightness, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo Yoga X1 2nd Gen laptop with Ubuntu 16.04

I have both windows 10 and ubuntu installed.

In windows, everything works fine, but in ubuntu when I press the brigghtness buttons, ubuntu shows me the value of the brightness is changing, but the actual brightness of the screen is not changing at all! I have tried most of the methods what I found online, like changing things in 20-intel.conf, grub. Neither of them worked. What should I do?

UPDATE:

xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness 1   # no dimming

the following command changes the brightness to max, and I can change the value 1 to something between 0 and 1 which then effectively changes the brightness. Is there a way to make the brightness keys work?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to enable brightness adjustment via the buttons by following the solution posted in https://askubuntu.com/a/862575/589172:

Create file: `/etc/acpi/events/yoga-brightness-up` with following content:

```
event=video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086
action=/etc/acpi/yoga-brightness.sh up
```

Create file: `/etc/acpi/events/yoga-brightness-down` with following content:

```
event=video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087
action=/etc/acpi/yoga-brightness.sh down
```

Create file `/etc/acpi/yoga-brightness.sh` with following content:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Where the backlight brightness is stored
BR_DIR="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/"


test -d "$BR_DIR" || exit 0

MIN=0
MAX=$(cat "$BR_DIR/max_brightness")
VAL=$(cat "$BR_DIR/brightness")

if [ "$1" = down ]; then
    VAL=$((VAL-71))
else
    VAL=$((VAL+71))
fi

if [ "$VAL" -lt $MIN ]; then
    VAL=$MIN
elif [ "$VAL" -gt $MAX ]; then
    VAL=$MAX
fi

PERCENT=`echo "$VAL / $MAX" | bc -l`

export XAUTHORITY=/home/ivo/.Xauthority  # CHANGE "ivo" TO YOUR USER
export DISPLAY=:0.0

echo "xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness $PERCENT" > /tmp/yoga-brightness.log
xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness $PERCENT

echo $VAL > "$BR_DIR/brightness"
```

Make it executable

```
chmod a+rx /etc/acpi/yoga-brightness.sh
```

Restart acpi by typing

```
sudo service acpid reload
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a Lenovo x1 yoga Gen 2 (OLED screen) and the solution mentioned in this repo worked.

https://github.com/udifuchs/icc-brightness