# Ubuntu 19.04 cannot change brightness on laptop

Tags: dell, brightness, xps

I recently purchased a Dell xps 15 9570 and installed ubuntu 19.04 onto it, removing windows 10. There were a lot of issues with ubuntu not being able to detect certain drivers but I was able to solve them. But one issue I cannot solve is the fact I cannot change the brightness via the functions keys. xbacklight doesn't work, the only way I can change the brightness, is by typing `xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness 0.4` into console.

The screen is OLED, also using intel's inbuilt UHD Graphics 630 and not nvidia but I have both.

Answer (score 2):

Ivo's (https://askubuntu.com/users/632873/ivo-bl%c3%b6chliger) solution at [Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Yoga OLED Brightness](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824949/lenovo-thinkpad-x1-yoga-oled-brightness) for a Yoga laptop also works for the Dell XPS 15-9570. The only thing I had to change was to subtract/add 6000 instead of the 71 in the script. That gives me a 20 step change, i.e. up/down by 5% for every key press.

This is what the modified solution looks like for the **XPS 15**, using similar three files. The first one is /etc/acpi/events/xps-brightness-up:

```
event=video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086
action=/etc/acpi/xps-brightness.sh up
```

nuber two is /etc/acpi/events/xps-brightness-down:

```
event=video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087
action=/etc/acpi/xps-brightness.sh down
```

and then the main script /etc/acpi/xps-brightness.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Where the backlight brightness is stored
BR_DIR="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/"


test -d "$BR_DIR" || exit 0

MIN=0
MAX=$(cat "$BR_DIR/max_brightness")
VAL=$(cat "$BR_DIR/brightness")

if [ "$1" = down ]; then
    VAL=$((VAL-6000))
else
    VAL=$((VAL+6000))
fi

if [ "$VAL" -lt $MIN ]; then
    VAL=$MIN
elif [ "$VAL" -gt $MAX ]; then
    VAL=$MAX
fi

PERCENT=`echo "$VAL / $MAX" | bc -l`

export XAUTHORITY=/home/user/.Xauthority  # CHANGE "user" TO YOUR USER
export DISPLAY=:0.0

echo "xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness $PERCENT" > /tmp/xps-brightness.log
xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness $PERCENT

echo $VAL > "$BR_DIR/brightness"
```

Don't forget to do a `chmod a+x /etc/acpi/xps-brightness.sh` and restart acpi by typing

```
sudo service acpid reload
```

I hope, this helps ;-)

Comment: I recommend that you **[edit]** this to also include the solution itself (with your modifications). I *think* you're referring to [P.Meyer's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/849642/22949) but I am not totally sure, which is why I didn't add this myself in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, not all PC makers make all of their equipment Ubuntu-ready, and the keyboard Dell selected for that laptop could be one of those. I checked, and Dell [does not offer Linux drivers](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/xps-15-7590-laptop/drivers) for that laptop. However, since it is new, they may have a solution anyway, so I'd suggest you contact Dell Support by [entering your Service Tag](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/xps-15-7590-laptop/overview).

In addition to the CLI command you found, there are more GUI methods for brightness adjustments at https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-brightness.html.en

Answer (score 0):

OLED screens do not usually provide hardware brightness levels.

There are many scripts available that will use `xrandr` to automatically set brightness and gamma at sunrise and sunset though.

On my Dell laptops I just shrink the size of Windows. I keep Windows around for gaming and to apply firmware updates from Dell.