# Dell XPS 15 9570 OLED brightness script

Tags: dell, brightness, 19.10

I've tried the solution at [Ubuntu 19.04 cannot change brightness on laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182796/ubuntu-19-04-cannot-change-brightness-on-laptop/1186390#1186390) but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I am using Ubuntu 19.10 instead of 19.04 as in that answer.

The main script `xps-brightness.sh` from that answer:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Where the backlight brightness is stored
BR_DIR="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight"

test -d "$BR_DIR" || exit 0

MIN=0
MAX=$(cat "$BR_DIR/max_brightness")
VAL=$(cat "$BR_DIR/brightness")

if [ "$1" = down ]; then
    VAL=$((VAL-6000))
else
    VAL=$((VAL+6000))
fi

if [ "$VAL" -lt $MIN ]; then
    VAL=$MIN
elif [ "$VAL" -gt $MAX ]; then
    VAL=$MAX
fi

PERCENT=`echo "$VAL / $MAX" | bc -l`

export XAUTHORITY=/home/derek/.Xauthority  # CHANGE "user" TO YOUR USER
export DISPLAY=:0.0

echo "xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness $PERCENT" > /tmp/xps-brightness.log
xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness $PERCENT

echo $VAL > "$BR_DIR/brightness"
```

When I use the brightness keys on my keyboard, both the value in `$BR_DIR/brightness` and the `/tmp/xps-brightness.log` log file get updated, but the script doesn't seem to execute the `xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness $PERCENT` command. This command works when I enter it directly into a console or in a script such as `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
xrand --output eDP-1 --brightness .7
```

and then run `sh test.sh`.

Why doesn't `xps-brightness.sh` work?

Comment: I have the same problem. 'but I got it to work yesterday no it does not anymore)